# MOSFET for revrerse voltage protection

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, zener, electrical

I have used the following circuit to for the purpose of reverse voltage protection. But, I am a little bit confuse about the working of the zener diode in combination of the 100k resistor in this circuit.

[image: MOSFET Circuit with Zener Diode]

So, what is the need of the zener diode in combination of the resistor in this circuit? How they are exactly working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, what is the need of the zener diode in combination of the resistor
>   in this circuit? How they are exactly working here?

The maximum gate source voltage for the FDN306P MOSFET is +/- 8 volts hence, on a 12 volt supply, if you didn't use a zener diode and the gate resistor you would be exceeding the limit specified in the data sheet.

[image]

Comment: But,in this circuit by turning on this power supply, i have measured the Gate and source voltage wrt GND. The source voltage is found to be 11.96 V and gate voltage is found to be 8.4.

Comment: Yes, and the difference between those voltages is 3.56 volts and pretty much what you'd get from a 5.6 volt zener operating on such light currents. Zeners are by no means perfect devices and don't magically switch from an open impedance to a short impedance at their zener voltage.

Comment: Now, removing only the Zener Diode (not the resistor), I found the same voltage as above. So, is there any problem in the circuit?

Comment: Without the zener, the gate source voltage would be excessive and potentially damage that junction. Once damaged it may naturally limit the voltage to a value lower than 12 volts.

Comment: OK,now I have understand a little bit. But is there any special role of the resistor. Can I connect the circuit in a similar manner only by using zener diode (only removing resistor)?

Comment: The protector also needs protection. The zener is the protector (of the mosfet gate source junction) and the resistor protects the 5.6 volt zener receiving a gaziliion amps from the 12 volt supply. The resistor can certainly be lower in value and still protect the zener of course.

Comment: Ok, but something is confusing still in my mind. Why and how the gate voltage is varying with the change in the supply voltage, in the circuit as show in my figure?

Comment: I have no idea why that should confuse you. If the gate is damaged, normal common sense analysis goes out of the window.

Comment: Actually, my question is not in this case. It was the previous case when the voltage difference between gate and source was coming 3.56(using zener). At that time when I was varying my supply voltage, the difference was also varying. Is it due to the change in the internal resistance of zener diode or other reason?

Comment: That could explain it.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the point of the zener diode is to prevent the \$V_{\rm GS}\$ voltage from getting too high, although I don’t think many MOSFET would not support a \$V_{\rm GS}\$ of 12V.

Comment: But,in this circuit by turning on this power supply, i have measured the Gate and source voltage wrt GND. The source voltage is found to be 11.96 V and gate voltage is found to be 8.4. Now, removing only the Zener Diode (not the resistor), I found the same voltage as above. So, is there any problem in the circuit? Again , when I vary the input voltage, the Gate and Source voltage changes in a linear way in both the cases. So, is this the ant property of MosFET or any other reason?

Comment: So,with the change in supply voltage, if the change in the gate voltage is controlling by the zener diode by varying its resistance, it will be fine. If my this point is right, then thanks for help and the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Your first and most major problem is that the [FDN306P](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDN306P-D.pdf) is totally inappropriate for this application.
Its datasheet shows it is a  -12V Absolute Maximum rated device. If you apply reverse voltage to this in your application it is already at its Absolute Maximum V(DS) rating. You should be selecting a device with a V(DS) rating of at least 15-20V.
The [FDN304](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDN304PZ-D.pdf) with a -20V rating would be a much more appropriate device to use.

It would be worth noting that by using an [FDN352](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDN352AP-D.pdf) with a greater V(GS) rating of 25V you could eliminate the resistor and Zener in your application. Given it's the same price as an FDN306 you save money on your application.

This would simplify your circuit to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9l2ur.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>